# How do I load an (unpacked) Chrome extension without any manfest.json file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created Chrome extensions in the past and always used a `manifest.json` to handle init.

Now I wanted to to some open-source dev on

```
https://github.com/manastungare/google-calendar-crx
```

but how do I start a dev environment?

When I want to load it in Chrome it complains about a missing `manifest.json`.

Comment: Why do you not create a `manifest.json` file?

Comment: Hmm, maybe so. What then I need to figure out what to put there. If there some method already inside the repo, then that seems like it would be easier...

Comment: _"What then I need to figure out what to put there."_ , _"I created Chrome extensions in the past and always used a `manifest.json`"_ See https://w3c.github.io/manifest/

Comment: What is the point of this post on your part? Prove to me how easy it is by posting a real answer with a solution and earn the reputation points instead. I am still under the assumption that a repo with 300+ commits and 35 contributors on Github has some standard way to run dev mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `manifest.json` file is within [`src`](https://github.com/manastungare/google-calendar-crx/tree/master/src) directory of repository. Download the repository and select the `src` directory after clicking "Load unpacked extension...".

Comment: Thanks! The key was to load `google-calendar-crx/src` instead of just ``google-calendar-crx`.